# group_by and summarise previously (10 minutes ago) worked on my data frame but no doesn't

Tags: r, group-by, tidyr

I have a dataframe I am manipulating that I ran `group_by` and summarise on a few minutes ago. After a forced restart of my computer (due to company IT) my `group_by` function no longer works. I have had this error sporadically for the last month or so.

Here's my code:

```
covid_per10k_hosp <- datasetv5_pat %>%
ungroup() %>% 
mutate(death2=case_when(death=="deceased"~1, TRUE~0)) %>% 
group_by(PROV_ID) %>% 
summarize(n_deaths=sum(death2))
```

example data:

```
PAT_ID    PROV_ID    death
1         A          deceased
2         A          alive
3         B          deceased
4         B          deceased
```

Expected Output:

```
PROV_ID     n_deaths
A           1
B           2
```

Actual Output:

```
PROV_ID    n_deaths
A          1
A          1
B          2
B          2
```

Edit to respond to comments suggesting additional information, here is the output from `sessionInfo()`

> ```
> R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)
> ```

```
Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United 
States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] finalfit_1.0.2     ggsci_2.9          icd_4.0.9             
ggpubr_0.4.0      
[5] readr_1.3.1        vroom_1.3.1        knitr_1.29         
tableone_0.12.0   
[9] dplyr_1.0.2        summarytools_0.9.6 expss_0.10.6       
Hmisc_4.4-1       
[13] ggplot2_3.3.2      Formula_1.2-3      survival_3.2-3     
lattice_0.20-38   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tidyr_1.1.1         bit64_4.0.5         splines_3.6.0       
carData_3.0-4      
 [5] assertthat_0.2.1    latticeExtra_0.6-29 pander_0.6.3        
cellranger_1.1.0   
 [9] pillar_1.4.6        backports_1.1.7     glue_1.4.2          
digest_0.6.25      
[13] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  pryr_0.1.4          ggsignif_0.6.0      
checkmate_2.0.0    
[17] colorspace_1.4-1    htmltools_0.5.0     Matrix_1.2-17          
survey_4.0         
[21] plyr_1.8.6          pkgconfig_2.0.3     broom_0.7.0         
haven_2.3.1        
[25] magick_2.4.0        purrr_0.3.4         scales_1.1.1        
jpeg_0.1-8.1       
[29] openxlsx_4.1.5      rio_0.5.16          htmlTable_2.0.1     
tibble_3.0.3       
[33] generics_0.0.2      car_3.0-9           ellipsis_0.3.1      
withr_2.2.0        
[37] nnet_7.3-12         cli_2.0.2           magrittr_1.5        
crayon_1.3.4       
[41] readxl_1.3.1        mice_3.11.0         fansi_0.4.1         
rstatix_0.6.0      
[45] forcats_0.5.0       foreign_0.8-71      rapportools_1.0     
tools_3.6.0        
[49] data.table_1.13.0   hms_0.5.3           mitools_2.4         
lifecycle_0.2.0    
[53] matrixStats_0.56.0  stringr_1.4.0       munsell_0.5.0       
cluster_2.0.8      
[57] zip_2.1.0           packrat_0.5.0       compiler_3.6.0      
rlang_0.4.7        
[61] grid_3.6.0          rstudioapi_0.11     htmlwidgets_1.5.1   
tcltk_3.6.0        
[65] base64enc_0.1-3     boot_1.3-22         gtable_0.3.0        
codetools_0.2-16   
[69] abind_1.4-5         DBI_1.1.0           curl_4.3            
R6_2.4.1           
[73] gridExtra_2.3       lubridate_1.7.9     utf8_1.1.4          
bit_4.0.4          
[77] stringi_1.4.6       Rcpp_1.0.5          vctrs_0.3.2             
rpart_4.1-15       
[81] png_0.1-7           tidyselect_1.1.0    xfun_0.16
```

Comment: Try `dplyr::summarize()`, as there might be a conflict...

Comment: can you please be more specific about what "no longer works" means?  Error (if so what error message)? Incorrect results (if so what results did you expect)?  Could we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - my new variables are created but my output is not grouped. I receive the following message: 
    `summarise()` regrouping output by 'PROV_ID' (override with `.groups` argument)

Previously, my 220k lines were summarized into 790 (the number of unique PROV_ID).

@YBS - I have tried that without any change. I also ensured plyr wasn't loaded and reloaded dplyr to be safe.

Comment: also useful: (1) results of `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()` (2) enough of your *actual* data set (using `dput()` or simulating something similar) to reproduce the problem on your end.

Comment: Restart R and re-run your script...

Comment: Restart RStudio or even reboot your laptop.  Sometimes that will resolve such issues.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this several times include a full reboot of my computer. Also, this isn't the first time I've experienced this issue but I've never been able to find a systematic reason for it occuring.